# Pendingintent is not working

Tags: android, android-intent, alarm, android-pendingintent

I'm making a multi Alarm app. I use PendingIntent in `AlarmMain.class`. But i don't know why Eclipse said that: The value of the local variable `mAlarmSender` is not used. 
(i used a `for` loop to send many `intent`)

```java
Intent intent = new Intent(AlarmMain.this,
                    OnBootReceiver.class);

intent.putExtra("hour", pieces[1]);

intent.putExtra("minute", pieces[2]);

PendingIntent mAlarmSender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AlarmMain.this, i, intent, 0);
```

And here is code `OnBootReceiver.class`:

```java
public class OnBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static Intent intent;

static Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

static String hour = bundle.getString("hour");

static String minute = bundle.getString("minute");

static Alarm alm;

public static void setAlarm(Context ctxt, Alarm alm) {
    OnBootReceiver.alm = alm;
    AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager)ctxt.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(hour));
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(minute));
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    android.util.Log.e("Alarm time!!", "The hour " + hour);
    android.util.Log.e("Alarm time!!", "The minute " + minute);
    if (cal.getTimeInMillis()<System.currentTimeMillis()) {
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
    }

    android.util.Log.e("***OnBootReceiver", android.text.format.DateFormat.format("MM/dd/yy h:mmaa", cal).toString());

    mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, getPendingIntent(ctxt));
    android.util.Log.e("Alarm time!!", "please help :((");
}

public static void cancelAlarm(Context ctxt) {
    AlarmManager mgr=(AlarmManager)ctxt.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    mgr.cancel(getPendingIntent(ctxt));
}

private static PendingIntent getPendingIntent(Context ctxt) {
    Intent i=new Intent(ctxt, OnAlarmReceiver.class);

    return(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctxt, 0, i, 0));
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {
    android.util.Log.e("****OnBootReceiver", "got here");    
    Intent i=new Intent(ctxt, AlarmActivity.class);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    ctxt.startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: @Franz Kafka: Thanks for editing style :)

Comment: You should go find an example of how to do this and study it. This code has a lot of issues. First, you are getting a `PendingIntent` using `getBroadcast()` but you aren't doing anything with it. Secondly, in `OnBootReceiver` you are initializing a number of static variables (`bundle`, `hour`, `minute`, etc) from  a null `Intent`. If this code were executed, it would crash with a `NullPointerException`.